# How can this not be a constant value?

Tags: c#, constants

I know this is probably just a terminology mismatch but if i'm not mistaken i believe c# is? unless i'm missing something obvious??

```
...
    private const uint URL_COUNT = 18;
    private string[] _urls;

    public Redirector()
    {
        this._urls = new string[URL_COUNT];
        ...
    }
...
```

Results in “A constant value is expected “ and underlines URL_COUNT in the array definition??

Whats URL_COUNT if it isn’t a **const** -ant value?!?!

**EDIT**
Phew, i thought for a second then i was going mad. I'm glad no one could repro this as that means it's just a local thing.
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: I plugged this into a new windows application and it compiled just fine and defined the array to the size in the const. Can you provide more information on where this is failing like is it a ASP.net code behind or a command line app, etc...

Comment: Well, are you absolutely sure that this is the exact code that does not compile? Or did you edit something out of there by mistake? I doubt it is just 'a local' thing. There are no 'local' differences between compilers (as far as I know, but pretty sure nonetheless).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will only fail to compile when you supply both the dimension lengths and an array initializer. For example:

```
this._urls = new string[URL_COUNT];
```

will be fine, but:

```
this._urls = new string[URL_COUNT] { "One", "Two" };
```

will not. The latter requires a constant *expression*. Note that a const variable is not a constant expression, just a constant value. From the C# specification (3.0) par 12.6:

> When an array creation expression
>   includes both explicit dimension
>   lengths and an array initializer, the
>   lengths must be constant expressions
>   and the number of elements at each
>   nesting level must match the
>   corresponding dimension length.

Comment: +1 This is a plausible explanation for the error.  I can't see any other way that this particular error could have been generated.

Comment: I removed the initialiser to simplify to example, i had no idea it could have been the cause of the problem!

Comment: Thought as much! Glad to have helped.

Comment: But a `const` field ***is*** a constant expression?

Comment: Yes, that's why the first example with only supplying the dimension (using the const field) is valid and will compile. The second example uses also an array initializer, which causes the error here.

Answer (score 5):

It is a constant and should work fine.  The following code compiled fine for me with the C# 3 compiler:

```
using System;

class Foo
{
    private const uint URL_COUNT = 18;
    private string[] _urls;

    public Foo()
    {
        this._urls = new string[URL_COUNT];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, can't repro this one either.

Comment: you need to supply both the initializer and a dimension length. I think the author accidentily edited the example code so it works :)

Answer (score 2):

This works too, without any complaints from the compiler.

```
class Foo {
    private const uint URL_COUNT = 18;
    private readonly string[] _urls = new string[URL_COUNT];
}
```